# Error: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I received this error when I running a Neural Network.

```
UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
 [[node sequential/conv2d/Relu (defined at <ipython-input-12-afdb1d683d38>:21) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1115]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

This is the code

```
seed = 10
np.random.seed(seed)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 10, shuffle = True, random_state = seed)
resultados = []
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=3)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

for indice_treinamento, indice_teste in kfold.split(x_train, np.zeros(shape = (y_train.shape[0],1))):
    model = Sequential()  

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = (51, 51, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), data_format='channels_last'))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = (51, 51, 3), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), data_format='channels_last'))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 

    model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
    model.fit(x_train[indice_treinamento], y_train[indice_treinamento], epochs = 30, batch_size = 128, callbacks=[es, mc], validation_data = (x_train[indice_teste], y_train[indice_teste]))
```

tensorflow-gpu 2.4.0

python 3.8.8

cuda v11.0

cuDNN v8.0.5.39

NVidia GeForce GTX 1660

Windows 10

Comment: This isn't a CUDA programming question and shouldn't be tagged as one.

Comment: Already removed

Comment: I get this error if I have more than one instance of python running which is using tensorflow. Try making sure only one instance of tensorflow is running.

Comment: @GabrielaMontes: I know, I removed it. Twice

Answer (score 0):

there are a few solutions to this issue:

- **Downgrading TF to 1.8.0**: For this,downgrading tensorflow to 1.8 and tf-gpu to 1.8 should work along with Cuda version 9.0 and corresponding CuDNN version (7.x.x preferably 7.2.4.24). Installation should be from pip. Also after installation, a manual verification should be made which ensures that correct version of CuDnn is installed. This [link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1043867/failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm-this-is-probably-because-cudnn-failed-to-initialize) should help.
- **Using TF nightly or TF2.0**: For this, tf-nightly-2.0-preview or higher versions can be installed. Also the following codebase should be added at the start of the code(model creation):

```py
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto

config = tensorflow.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tensorflow.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
sess.as_default()
```

Alternatively for Keras and TF2.0, this can be tested as :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
keras.backend.set_session(sess)
keras.backend.get_session().run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

- **Determine GPU availability**: If the 2 methods do not work, then this may help:

```py
import logging
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if physical_devices:
    try:
        for device in physical_devices:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, True)
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error(err)
```

- **Delete and Reinstall Cuda**: This is another way, for this issue hardware version problems may be present. Hence a proper version of CUDNN should be installed (7.4.x) from Nvidia. An elaborate description can be found in this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24828)

Hope this solution works.